# SQl query working only 5 out of 18 cases. The counting of items seems to be wrong somewhere

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's passing for 5 cases but not all.
Question is: Write an SQL query to find for each user, the join date and the number of orders they made as a buyer in 2019.
Return the result table in any order.
Users table:

```
+---------+------------+----------------+
| user_id | join_date  | favorite_brand |
+---------+------------+----------------+
| 1       | 2018-01-01 | Lenovo         |
| 2       | 2018-02-09 | Samsung        |
| 3       | 2018-01-19 | LG             |
| 4       | 2018-05-21 | HP             |
+---------+------------+----------------+
```

Orders table:

```
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| order_id | order_date | item_id | buyer_id | seller_id |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 2019-08-01 | 4       | 1        | 2         |
| 2        | 2018-08-02 | 2       | 1        | 3         |
| 3        | 2019-08-03 | 3       | 2        | 3         |
| 4        | 2018-08-04 | 1       | 4        | 2         |
| 5        | 2018-08-04 | 1       | 3        | 4         |
| 6        | 2019-08-05 | 2       | 2        | 4         |
+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+


WITH CTE AS (
SELECT buyer_id,  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orders_in_2019
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY buyer_id 
)

SELECT C.buyer_id, U.join_date, C.orders_in_2019
FROM CTE C 
LEFT JOIN Users U 
ON U.user_id = C.buyer_id
order by 1
```

COUNT(*) won't work as it would not count 0's for buyers who didn't buy any item in 2019

```
 Output: Should look like:
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| buyer_id  | join_date  | orders_in_2019 |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 1         | 2018-01-01 | 1              |
| 2         | 2018-02-09 | 2              |
| 3         | 2018-01-19 | 0              |
| 4         | 2018-05-21 | 0              |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Switch the tables for the left join

Comment: Please explain: "COUNT(*) won't work as it would not count 0's", because https://dbfiddle.uk/nDvGDH1k

Comment: I mean, the rows with other years will be removed in the where clause for them to count later.

Answer (score 1):

```
select     distinct u.user_id buyer_id
          ,join_date
          ,count(case year(o.order_date) when 2019 then 1 end) over(partition by u.user_id) orders_in_2019
          
from       users u join orders o on o.buyer_id = u.user_id
```

| buyer_id | join_date | orders_in_2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2018-02-09 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2018-01-19 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 4 | 2018-05-21 00:00:00 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uE94DDf5?hide=4)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it will not count 0's for all the years other than 2019!!!    It should show user_id join_date number_of_orders
3 - 0 and 4 - 0  Since there's no buying for them in the year 2019.

Comment: @Tushar see updated answer

Comment: I ran the code against the leetcode server, which is still working for 5 cases. Here's the leetcode link https://leetcode.com/problems/market-analysis-i/

Comment: show me the cases it doesn't work in

Comment: The cases are pretty long. Is it possible for you to run the leetcode problem and test it there?

Comment: @Tushar it works. the only thing you had to change was the name of the column. run it now.

Comment: Is there anything I can do with my code to get it passed all cases? I am trying to understand what I did wrong.